# switch columns in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, multiple-columns

How do you switch columns around via regexp in Notepad++? For example I have this data set

> user.Email|recipient.CreationDate|recipient.MessagePK|user.CustomAttribute.Correspondence_ID

but I want it to be:

> user.Email|recipient.MessagePK|recipient.CreationDate|user.CustomAttribute.Correspondence_ID

Moving the data rows underneath the columns also.

Answer (score 10):

**Change the order of columns 1,2,3,4 to 2,4,1,3:**

1. Click Ctrl/H.
2. Choose Regular Expression (bottom left side of the popup window).
3. Find what: `(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)`
4. Replace with: `\2|\4|\1|\3`

Comment: I did this:

(.user.Email)\|(.recipient.CreationDate)\|(.recipient.MessagePK)\|(.user.CustomAttribute.Correspondence_ID)

\1\|\3\|\2\|\4\

But the columns were not moved..

Comment: You have `.` inside the expression. This is a special character in Notepad++ Regular Expression. Use `\.` instead.

Comment: There're no needs to escape the pipe `|` in the replace part.